# Solr upgrading from 1.4 to 3.5

Tags: solr

I'm trying to upgrade our Solr instance from a patched 1.4 build to 3.5, but I seem to be having a strange issue with searching. Any standard searches will work fine, but my dismax handler fails. Well, not really fails but it doesn't give me any results. If I try to enable debugging I get the following error:

```
Problem accessing /solr/select. Reason:

null

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.DebugComponent.process(DebugComponent.java:52)
at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:202)
at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129)
...
```

I'm completely stumped as to what is happening here.

Relevant part of the solrconfig.xml:

```
<requestHandler name="dismax" class="solr.SearchHandler">
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="defType">dismax</str>
    <str name="mm">100%</str>
    <int name="ps">100</int>
    <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.count">25</str>
    <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>facet</str>
    <str>debug</str>
    <str>spellcheck</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Problem resolved: the issue was a combination of <arr name="components"> should be <arr name="last-components"> and the spellcheck component was configured wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<str>debug</str>` and use debugQuery=true if you want debug information.

Comment: This got rid of the NullPointerException when I use debugQuery=true, but it still does not return any results and it does not return any debug information to use for finding out why.